# Implementing own Android CursorAdapter for search suggestions - unknown exceptions

Tags: java, android, sqlite, searchview, android-cursoradapter

I have implemented my own cursor adapter to manually handle suggestions, so that I can get rid of the overkill method that android docs proposes.
Basically what I do is setOnQueryTextListener to the actionbar searchview after it's been inflated. Everytime the user inputs a new search text, I query a Sqlite db which returns a cursor. Finally, I create my own cursor adapter with the retrieved cursor and set it to the searchview with setSuggestionsAdapter method.
The problem here is that I am getting many unknown exceptions depending on the way I update the cursor everytime the config changes. I'exaplin it later, first some code:

************************ My own cursor adapter class ************************

public class BusStopCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

```
public BusStopCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor, false);

}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    //set address
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.address)).setText(cursor.getString(1));
    //set line
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.line)).setText(cursor.getString(2));

}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.suggestions_layout, parent, false);

    //set address
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.address)).setText(cursor.getString(1));
    //set line
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.line)).setText(cursor.getString(2));


    return view;

}
}
```

*********************** the listener added to the searchView *******************

```
        // Associate searchView listeners
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            System.out.println("QUERY STRING: "+newText);
            Cursor cursor = queryData(newText);
            searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(new BusStopCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), cursor));

            return true;
        }
    });
```

In this case, what I do to update the cursor is drastically add a brand new adapter. At first everything goes well, but when a config change happens I get this log:

```
03-10 15:20:11.762    1927-1927/com.nikkis.vallabus I/System.out﹕ QUERY STRING: ad
03-10 15:20:13.012    1927-1927/com.nikkis.vallabus I/System.out﹕ QUERY STRING: ado
03-10 15:20:13.992    1927-1927/com.nikkis.vallabus I/System.out﹕ QUERY STRING: adol
03-10 15:20:15.602    1927-1927/com.nikkis.vallabus I/System.out﹕ QUERY STRING:
03-10 15:20:15.602    1927-1927/com.nikkis.vallabus I/System.out﹕ QUERY STRING: adol
03-10 15:20:15.662    1927-1927/com.nikkis.vallabus W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
03-10 15:20:15.672    1927-1927/com.nikkis.vallabus W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
03-10 15:20:15.722    1927-1927/com.nikkis.vallabus W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-10 15:20:15.812    1927-1927/com.nikkis.vallabus W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-10 15:20:15.882    1927-1927/com.nikkis.vallabus W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
03-10 15:20:18.402    1927-1927/com.nikkis.vallabus I/System.out﹕ QUERY STRING:
03-10 15:20:18.402    1927-1927/com.nikkis.vallabus I/System.out﹕ QUERY STRING: adol
03-10 15:20:18.492    1927-1927/com.nikkis.vallabus W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
03-10 15:20:18.492    1927-1927/com.nikkis.vallabus W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
03-10 15:20:18.522    1927-1927/com.nikkis.vallabus W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-10 15:20:18.552    1927-1927/com.nikkis.vallabus W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-10 15:20:18.592    1927-1927/com.nikkis.vallabus W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
```

The application seems to work fine. The only unexplainable issue (probably regarding to these exceptions) is that after a config change sometimes the suggestions appear and sometimes dont. Is like if it couldnt perform the query or something.

If for example I use this alternative listener implementation which updates just the cursor (as it should be the cleanest way) instead of recreating the whole adapter the thing gets even worse: I get unknown SQL error (which shouldnt be there as the sql query works perfeclty), some kind of cursor column access error(either shouldnt be there as the suggestions are being shown) and the app eventually crashes.

************************* Alternative listener**********************************

```
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            System.out.println("QUERY STRING: "+newText);
            Cursor cursor = queryData(newText);
         /*   if (newText !="")
            searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(new BusStopCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), cursor));*/

            if (searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter() == null) {
                searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(new BusStopCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), cursor));
            } else {
                searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter().changeCursor(cursor);
            }

            return true;
        }
```

****************************** the crashing log*********************************

```
03-10 15:58:46.762    3767-3767/com.nikkis.vallabus  W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-10 15:58:46.792    3767-3767/com.nikkis.vallabus W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
03-10 15:58:48.612    3767-3767/com.nikkis.vallabus I/System.out﹕ QUERY STRING:
03-10 15:58:48.622    3767-3767/com.nikkis.vallabus I/System.out﹕ QUERY STRING: adol
03-10 15:58:48.632    3767-4304/com.nikkis.vallabus W/Filter﹕ An exception occured during performFiltering()!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery: SELECT stop.stopID AS _id, stop.address, stop_line.line FROM stop_line, stop WHERE stop.stopID = stop_line.stop AND stop.address LIKE '%%';
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:143)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
        at android.widget.CursorFilter.performFiltering(CursorFilter.java:53)
        at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
03-10 15:58:48.652    3767-3767/com.nikkis.vallabus W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
03-10 15:58:48.652    3767-3767/com.nikkis.vallabus W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
03-10 15:58:48.652    3767-4304/com.nikkis.vallabus E/CursorWindow﹕ Failed to read row 0, column 0 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 0 columns.
03-10 15:58:48.702    3767-3767/com.nikkis.vallabus W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-10 15:58:48.792    3767-3767/com.nikkis.vallabus W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-10 15:58:48.832    3767-3767/com.nikkis.vallabus W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
```

I would appreciate some help as I am completely stuck after spending hours of searching. Thanks in advance.

Comment: call setSuggestionsAdapter ONCE and setup FilterQueryProvider in that adaptet

Comment: also you dont need any setOnQueryTextListener: just call setSuggestionsAdapter() once in onCreateOptionsMenu and that's it

Comment: Thank you for your anser pskink but I think I am missing something about how it works. What I suppose is that:
1. You receive a new input text via the setOnQueryTextListener.
2. You query the database with that text.
3. The database returns a cursor that you changes to the adapter.
4. The suggestions listview gets updated.

Is this way how it works? Because I cant understand why it fails. What is that FilterQueryProvider for?

Comment: no, no need for setOnQueryTextListener, just call myAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(this) and searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(myAdapter) in onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: myAdapter can be just SimpleCursorAdapter, no need for a custom one

Comment: But then who is in charge of requering the database for a new cursor each time the user inputs a new text? (Btw I am using a custom adapter to populate custom layout).

Comment: FilterQueryProvider, it returns a Cursor in runQuery: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FilterQueryProvider.html

Comment: So it automatically calls FilterQueryProvider everytime the user changes the input text?

Comment: yes, this is exactly what it does try this: http://pastebin.com/Y7XMR4vi

Comment: oh, I thought it goes that way due to a misleading tutorial. Thank you very much, I am just going to code and try it. If you post an answer you deserve a +.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have over-complicated this: there is no need for setOnQueryTextListener, just call:

```
myCursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(this);
searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
```

in `onCreateOptionsMenu`, you will need your Activity to implement `FilterQueryProvider` where in its `runQuery` you return your `Cursor` with suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Just tried it. It works like a charm. The query is working on config changes and it doesnt crash anymore. The only issue is that I am getting these exceptions in logcat everytime the config changes:

```
03-10 19:39:06.542  30711-30711/com.nikkis.vallabus W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-10 19:39:06.622  30711-30711/com.nikkis.vallabus W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-10 19:39:06.672  30711-30711/com.nikkis.vallabus W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
03-10 19:39:08.252  30711-30711/com.nikkis.vallabus W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: no idea what it can be... is it yours? com.nikkis.vallabus?

Comment: that is the application package name.

Comment: do you still use OnQueryTextListener ?

Comment: No, I have already removed it. Don't know what can be. Maybe it is due to something missing when extending CursorAdapter.

Comment: i dont know, never saw such warnings, to be sure, for testing purposes try SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: Thanks anyway for your suppot, you saved my day after wasting hours of googling :)

Comment: your welcome, que son muy bienvenidos (not sure if it's right :)

Comment: Haha, actually it is "eres bienvenido" but nice try! Would ask you where are you from and some other android related questions but I guess this is not a chat room :( .Btw I ve just browsed your github libraries, very useful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72696/discussion-between-quark-and-pskink).