# live searching on the actionbar's searchView

Tags: android, filtering, searchview

i was wondering onto how we can implement/ create a list View below the search view widget on the action bar. And finally filter the list when a string is entered just like the one on the Google play store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);   

    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String cs) 
        {
            YourActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            YourActivity.this.adapter.setTextToFilter(cs);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) 
        {
            YourActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            YourActivity.this.adapter.setTextToFilter(query);
            return false;
        }
    };
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListener);
```

place this code in oncreateOptionMenu in your activity

it works only using arrayadapter

Comment: Thanks and all guys, but i want to know how you implemented the adapter without a list view. If there is a listView how did you implement it to be below the action bar

Comment: @I'amNaolKebede see my comments below then

Answer (score 0):

When you [configure a `SearchView`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#ConfiguringWidget), you call `setSearchableInfo()`. Per the [Adding Custom Suggestions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html) training, this involves adding a line such as

```
android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.example.MyCustomSuggestionProvider"
```

to your `searchable.xml`. Then you must implement a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html#CustomContentProvider) that can handle incoming search queries.

Comment: actually there is a much easier way: OnQueryTextListener

Comment: @pskink - if you know of a way to tie a `OnQueryTextListener` to a suggestions dropdown of a SearchView, please do write an answer. However, you'll find the built in SearchView does not have a mechanism to provide a dropdown of suggestions based on anything but a properly created `ContentProvider`'s results.

Comment: i see that OP doesn't want a dropdown but rather wants a separate filterable ListView and even if he wanted a dropdown you can use  setSuggestionsAdapter (CursorAdapter adapter) or i am missing something?

Comment: @pskink - he mentions the Play Store, which does not have a ListView below its search (instead, uses a dropdown). The CursorAdapter needs to return a Cursor in the exact format as is listed in that Custom suggestions training - looking forward to your answer on implementing filtering in that without the backing ContentProvider

Comment: i'm a bit lost with your comment, so you agree that you you can use your own CursorAdapter without implementing a ContentProvider and without declaring searchable.xml?

Comment: @pskink - you're the expert on that approach. I've never seen that way implemented successfully and would not recommend it.

Comment: its quite easy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28971530/2252830 see basic implementation here: http://pastebin.com/Y7XMR4vi

Comment: @pskink I saw the basic implementation on the pastebin page but have no idea on how to fill in the URI.withappendpath...

Comment: @ianhanniballake can you show me an implementation, if im not asking too much